# Continous monitoring of a state using while statement

Tags: python

I am trying to continously monitor a state of a device using While True statement. the project is almost done. I am facing problem when putting it in production.

Code :

```
while True:
    # monitor the state of this device..
    # when ever this device state changes .
    # raise an alert.
    # 
    break
```

This is the algorithm on which it works. But when i try to continously monitor the system, the CPU is being used continously and the script utilizes continously some 30% of the CPU. I want to reduce it to zero. Is it possible in python ?

I cannot use `time.sleep(sec)` as this has to be very precise. Kindly help me in solving out this problem..

Comment: How "very" precise you need to be? Try `sleep(0.1)`, it works on may systems. If you need millisecond precision, probably Python is not the right tool.

Answer (score 2):

What is the "device", is it actually a device like a piece of hardware?  Or is it a software component of yours?

Don't poll continously, you need to redesign so that when the device state changes it emits a *signal*, and you can register interest in that signal using a callback function.

You should google for the observer design pattern, here is a nice python example I have used in the past: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/131499-observer-pattern/

Comment: If there is no native way to register for a "signal" to be emitted, OP will still need to implement one using some form of polling.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to sleep then, yes, you going to use up some CPU. That's not *necessarily* a bad thing. If nothing else needs the CPU then it's quite acceptable to peg it at 100% if you need to (power saving notwithstanding).

If your concern is that you simply don't want to wait a whole second to catch the event, you can provide a floating point value:

```
import time
time.sleep (0.1)
```

The difference between the following two programs shows how even a small delay helps out, based on running `top` under Ubuntu 11.04, Python 2.7.1:

```
# Will peg at 100%         # Won't even reach 1%
import time                import time
while True:                while True:
    pass                       time.sleep(0.01)
                               pass
```

---

If, as you seem to indicate in a comment, you don't want to use *any* CPU until the device changes status, then polling is not the way to go (despite the fact that the code above seems to indicate that polling with a small delay is perfectly viable).

You'll have to redesign things to be interrupt-driven, where the device *notifies* a process that the state has changed.

You haven't really provided enough information in the question (about the device or environment) for us to help you out there, so the general advice to switch from polling to interrupt-driven behaviour is all I've got.

Comment: I am concerned only about the CPU process. it is shooting up when i start this script to 60% and settles down at 30% continously. This cannot happen. The script should silently listen and be in idle state till there is a change in the device status.

Comment: @Bala - then don't poll. You need an interrupt-driven strategy if you want that sort of behaviour.

Comment: The device is actually a hardware like (external HDD & other periferals). i am writing a script that will keep monitoring the changes. All the external HDD's are connected using USB. I wanted to keep track of all the HDD and its connection state. Many a time, i face problems with the disconnection of the External Disk as a result of which, we face issues. Also need to monitor the Ethernet status, and update when there is switch in traffic between 2 ethernets. So i mostly used While true: statements to check the status espicially for the drives. Facing issues with CPU utilization.

Comment: Because of which i am afraid to implement this in the production servers. Even if its going to be a event driven programming, then i have to hook into some dll??? is that what you mean ??

Comment: @Bala - see the update. Polling with a small delay will almost certainly suffice, without the (likely massive) effort of re-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

chances are you don't *really* don't want to poll something continuously in a while loop, as fast as your processor allows.

run this:

```
while True:
    pass
```

notice your cpu is now pegged at 100% utilized (or at least 1 core is).